# createRecord is creating a record with null

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have hasMany property.
Here is my model

```
status: DS.attr(), 
    OnInsert: DS.attr('boolean',{defaultValue: true}),
    rOnUpdate: DS.attr('boolean',{defaultValue: false}),
    filterQuery:DS.attr({defaultValue: {"condition": "AND", "subRules": [], "subGroups" : []}}),
    ruleCase:DS.hasMany('rule',{async:true}),
```

In my hbs i have created button with some action on it:
Here is my hbs code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" {{action 'createrecord'}}>Case</button>
```

Then in the controllers i have defined this action:
Here is my controller code:

```
actions:{
    createrecord:function(){
        return this.store.createRecord('rulecase');
    }
}
```

But every time when i click on the add button it creates an empty record with id =null because on which i am not able to iterate over model.ruleCase.
How to overcome this problem????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're wanting is to be able to associate the new rulecase to the model, you don't need an ID for it.
Modify the createRecord method and push it to model.ruleCase

```
createrecord:function(){
    const newRulecase = this.store.createRecord('rulecase');
    model.get('ruleCase').pushObject(newRulecase)
    return newRulecase;
}
```

If there's some other reason that's causing you to need an ID, you can generate one on the client side using [generateIdForRecord](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.4/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter/methods/generateIdForRecord?anchor=generateIdForRecord).  You'll need to generate an adapter file for the ruleCase model and apply the logic for the ID.